# Can't change ColorPicker layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change the contents of the ColorPicker widget, so alpha channel, hsv and other fields except rgb are not needed. I opened the source code of the widget and tried to make some changes, but I could not find what is responsible for adding any fields
ColorPicker source - https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/colorpicker.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify the default one why not you (hard) code a custom one youself ?

Comment: The `ColorPicker` layout is defined in the `style.kv` file in your kivy installation.